# Have plans for Python 4 been resurrected?

Tags: python

I just started noticing deprecation notices like the following in the official Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html):

> Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 4.0.

I had been led to believe based on a number of public statements (such as this [article with excerpts interview with Guido](https://medium.com/codex/python-4-0-will-never-arrive-3d994dce54f1)) that there would never be a Python 4, but now I'm starting to wonder if he (or the Python maintainers) may have recently had a change of mind. Or are these deprecation notices just a humorous way of saying "this feature will never be removed"? You never know with someone who names his language after a comedy team.

Comment: Good question. Here's an interesting article: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/programming-languages-why-python-4-0-will-probably-never-arrive-according-to-its-creator/

Comment: Am I supposed to take an article seriously that says Python "will bе availablе on all platforms, not just Windows"?

Comment: *"just started noticing deprecation notices like the following"* ... which was [added in 2012](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/029780be09ab5483ac4562d795ea4b4b6d456f44), so it's a bit odd to talk as if that's a recent development.

Comment: @nocomment Nice find. For reference, here's the relevant BPO issue: [13072: Getting a buffer from a Unicode array uses invalid format](https://bugs.python.org/issue13072). (The link on GitHub goes to [PR 13072](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13072), which is incorrect.)

Comment: @kelly Pretty sure that refers to the performance enhancements  he's  working on as a Microsoft employee (or contractor). I've read more carefully-worded statements to that effect elsewhere.

Comment: @nocomment I think what's more recent is the clearing up of earlier assumptions that Python would probably keep going with major version numbering. I was surprised to find that the official documentation still hadn't caught up.

Comment: I know at one point there was no plan to avoid a Python 4, only no plans for a version 4 to introduce the same kind of backwards compatibility issues that Python 3 introduced. (I vaguely recall a statement indicating that Python 4 would just be Python 3.10, although whether that was a plan to actually avoid double-digit minor version numbers, or just a way of saying that the switch to Python 4 would be no more significant than any other minor-version bump, I don't know.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People like to repeat that one sound bite, but Guido had more to say on the subject, like:

> Van Rossum didn't rule out the possibility of Python 4.0 entirely,
> though suggested this would likely only happen in the event of major
> changes to compatibility with C. "I could imagine that at some point
> we are forced to abandon certain binary or API compatibility for C
> extensions… If there was a significant incompatibility with C
> extensions without changing the language itself and if we were to be
> able to get rid of the GIL [global interpreter lock]; if one or both
> of those events were to happen, we probably would be forced to call it
> 4.0 because of the compatibility issues at the C extension level," he said.

(source: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/programming-languages-why-python-4-0-will-probably-never-arrive-according-to-its-creator/ - which contains a link to a video with more, if you have the time)

So the upshot of it seems to be that there will never be a Python 4, unless the advantages of making backwards compatibility breaking changes are so great, they simply dwarf the massive downsides that have become so apparent from the 2-to-3 change.

Programmers and programming language designers are pragmatic people, generally speaking. If the benefit outweighs the cost, it will happen eventually. Nobody has anything to gain from religious zeal about design choices.

Comment: Thanks. Marking the answer as accepted. Still hoping someone will be able to shed some authoritative light on what the deprecation messages actually mean now.